# Обнуление NSManagedObject подкласса

Tags: objective-c, ios, coredata

Некоторое действие с нажатия ячейки в `tableView` производит новый объект и переходит на другой `viewController`:

```
    User *user = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self.delegate setSupervisorGUID:user.server_id supervisorTitle:user.name];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

на этом же `viewController`'е есть кнопка которая должна тоже менять `viewController` но  без установки значения (обнуление объекта как опция отмены действия) :

```
    [self.delegate setSupervisorGUID:[NSNull null] supervisorTitle:user.name];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Такой вариант решает задачу но понятное дело некорректен с точки зрения логики и конечно дает `warning`. Как правильно решить вопрос?

Comment: Уточнение - supervisor - имеет значение только для того другого viewController или для всего работающего приложения целиком? Иначе: сведения о supervisor используются только в том другом контроллере или и за его пределами? Еще иначе - как используются данные supervisor?

Comment: Да, и еще: какой конкретно warning выдается?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как выяснилось, надобности создавать связанный объект с пустыми полями (либо обнулять его) нет, так как по сути операция отмены действия не предполагала необходимости наличия объекта. Важным фактором являлось то что сведения о `supervisor` были локальными только по отношению к одному контроллеру а не глобально к проекту как заметил [@Stanislaw Pankevich](/users/10139/stanislaw-pankevich).